# Zxing construcing binarybitmap from a gray scale image android

Tags: android, zxing, luminance

i am developing an android application it has a requirement of decoding gray scale images which contains qr codes. i have been trying to integrate zxing with android . for rgb color scale images it's working fine.

for rgb image byte array i have used this code to build the binarybitmap.

```
RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, data);
BinaryBitmap Binary_bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
```

but for gray scale image i don't know how to build the binarybitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply using `LuminanceSource` without the RGB. Works fine for grayscale images, though I'm using a buffered image. So that would be `LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(grayscaleImg);`

Should you need to convert your mat to a buffered image, do this:

```
BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(mat.width(), mat.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) gray.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
mat.get(0, 0, data);
```